# Dynamically change color of text in cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

How to change text color dynamically in js file in ionic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because Ionic use angular,
you can use **ng-style**.

if you an element like this:

Sample Text

You can change color with this code:

```
$scope.myStyle = "{ 'color': 'red' }"
```

more details can be found in [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle).